# How can I estimate the cooking time of a roast?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, temperature, home-experiment

I never remember what worked before, or to write it down someplace.  In any case the size and starting temperature will vary.  The instructions I learned from refuse to give a time at all, and the first time my guests were waiting hours past the expected dinner time; another time it was ready so early that I had to call everyone to come right away.

For dinner every Jan 1 I make a [rib roast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_rib_roast):

[image: rib roast from wikipedia]

which I cook very slowly, [as taught](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/Season5/Roast/RoastTranscript.htm) by “Good Eats”.  I no longer use the flower pot, though, as the oven is good enough to use a open roasting pan.

To summarize, this is the slow method of putting in an oven (or bury a crock in the coals) at (a mere) 200°F

The main variable for me would be the starting temperature.  From the ’fridge, it might be a chilly 40° in the center, or might be 52, or anything really depending on how it was aged and when it was taken out.  The size is 10 pounds, which is 4 bones.  The cross section is the same as the generic picture, but mine is about twice as tall (tall in the photo; but that's width in the oven, if it matters).

So we start out with a thermal gradient, and *end* that step with a thermal gradient too, as the heat still moves toward the center even after it's removed from the oven.  I expect about 10 degrees of “carry over”, which should tell you something about the thermal properties of the material.

Can someone help me with a quick **thermodynamic formula** that will tell me the expected time until the external heat should be removed, based on the starting temperature of the center?  Then, what should I be expecting for equilibrium if the outside is insulated, and how long would that take?

(actually I don't really need to to reach equilibrium because I return to a very hot oven to char the outside; but that's fast enough that the center doesn't know what's happening and intermediate locations are still working on the wave of temp. difference from the original 200° bake).

Comment: Using a meat thermometer is much simpler than estimating shapes, and using formulas. http://whatscookingamerica.net/Information/MeatTemperatureChart.htm

Comment: Yes, the thermometer will tell me when it's reached the temperature.  I use two.  I know what temperature I'm aiming for, as noted in the question.  I just don't want to be *aimless* as knowing when it will be dinner time (as explained in the post).

Comment: here is a recipe similar to your . timing is 4 to 6 hours, the delta(t) is large .   http://www.chow.com/recipes/30234-slow-roasted-prime-rib-au-jus?page=all

Comment: ΔT is large? No kidding.  Thanks for the link, @annav

Comment: I found some papers where they model cylinders, but explicitly exclude "lumpy" ones as a roast. The conductivity of "lumpy" must be the what makes for large time variations, different for different lambs.

Comment: So, the real appeal of hotdogs is revealed: homogeneous emulsified material of uniform dimension can always be cooked to perfection and with exact timing.

Comment: There is an inevitable amount of "aimlessness" when you are cooking a slow roast. There are just too many variables: the calibration of your oven; the distribution of fat, bones, and meat within the roast; and surface area versus mass. Add even more uncertainty if you cook outside with a slow smoker (the best, yum!). Recipes will give you a base value for how long you need to cook, but a thermometer is the only thing that will tell you when the meat is done and time is up.

Comment: Would [cooking.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Typically meat at the usual oven temperature of 350 F takes about 20 minutes per
pound. The objective is to get the interior of the roast cooked which means getting it
up to between 160 F and 170 F.

In Short, you are using an convection oven at 350 degrees to raise the temperature
of the meat from around 70 F to 170 F, a rise of 100 F in  N minutes.

If the oven is only at 200 F, does it make sense that it will take a lot longer
to raise the temperature of the meat to 160 F to 170 F.

350 - 70 = 280
200 - 70 = 130

280 / 100 = 2.8
130 / 100 = 1.3

2.8/1.3 = 2.154  Times as long.  so 43 minutes per pound.

I would use less than this number though, as it is impossible to
fix when it is overcooked.

Comment: 160°F ? what kind of meat are you familiar with?  Alton Brown notes, “Toast: 146° and up”, and “narrow range of joy  in between 127 and about 132”.

Comment: 160°F ? What kind of Physicist are you? Either use Kelvins or Rankines!

Comment: Fahrenheits are priceless.